# Understanding complex pointer sample code in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand the following snippet of a sample pointer program, not sure if it's possible to ask these questions, I'll delete if it isn't!

```
void f1(char *s) {
    char *p, *q;
    for (p=q=s; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        if ((*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z') || (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z'))
            *q++ = *p;
        else if (q > s && *(q-1) != '\n')
            *q++ = '\n';
    }
    *q = '\0';
}
```

I understand there are three pointers p, s and q, but I'm not sure what `p=q=s` entails? Is it checking if both pointers p and q are between `char` a-z (one is lower case the other is upper case) and iterating through the letters?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you know that you use `’` instead of `'` for characters?

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was my prof's example in the slides. I will change it.

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger. Test the code with a few random strings and debug it when it runs. That should give you some insight in what the code actually does.

Answer (score 3):

Answering your questions, the snipped tokenize a string into lines if a character is not a letter, it also group tokens together and strip if it is in the first line, but not in the last, where it will leave up to one newline.

Commenting it:

```
void f1(char *s) {
     /* Two pointers, q for writing and p for reading */
    char *p, *q;

    /* Initialize both at the beginning and start looping the input string */
    for (p=q=s; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        /* If it is a letter, just keep it */
        if ((*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z') || (*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z'))
            *q++ = *p;
        /* If not, increment the write pointer only if the last
           is not a newline with boundary check */
        else if (q > s && *(q-1) != '\n')
            *q++ = '\n';
    }
    *q = '\0';
}
```

If you input:

```
char var [] = "    THIS.is a    STRING\n"
              "with two lines...";
```

It will result:

```
THIS
is
a
STRING
with
two
lines
/*with one newline at the end */
```

Comment: Hi thank you for writting up the sample code to test it out! I just did the steps on pen and paper using example blah2blah4 and got it to tokenize blah blah (if that makes sense), your explanation is a lot better though! Appreciate it. :) I'm not sure if the newline is intended or not either LOL.

Comment: And what's really confusing in the original code, uh?

Comment: @bipll hahaha... that can be an unsigned long long int discussion.

Comment: IMO yours is more confusing, having to read both -- and ++, and realise that your '\n' is going to be overwritten next iteration. I'd go for `if(is_replace(*pread) && pwrite > str_to_tokenize && *(pwrite-1) != '\n') { *pwrite = '\n' ; pwrite ++; }` , (omitting the bottom pwrite++), as a best of both worlds

Comment: @JosephIreland : same here. I could understand the original in one ~30 sec read. Attempting to read this one, I jumped out after 15sec. BTW: IMHO the `*(q-1)` notation in the original is pathetic. Normal people would write `q[-1]`

Comment: Ok. Yours comments are very valid, and I admit my post is tendentious, so I'm gonna edit it to avoid getting off topic. Even though we got some nice points about readability.

Answer (score 0):

if we look at `for (p=q=s; *p != '\0'; p++)` that basically means before the for loop begins, set `p = s`, and `q = s`. In C speak that means p, q and s are initially set up to equal the same string (or more specifically, pointing to the same address)

Answer (score 0):

A version using indexes instead of pointers:

```
void f1(char *buf) {
    size_t src, dst;
    for (src=dst=0; buf[src]; src++) {
        if ((buf[src] >= 'A' && buf[src] <= 'Z') || (buf[src] >= 'a' && buf[src] <= 'z'))
            buf[dst++] = buf[src];
        else if (dst && buf[dst-1] != '\n')
            buf[dst++] = '\n';
    }
    *q = '\0';
}
```

---

And the same in *Kernighan-style*:

```
void f1(char *buf) {
    size_t src, dst;
    for (src=dst=0; buf[dst] = buf[src]; src++) {
        if (buf[src] >= 'A' && buf[src] <= 'Z' || buf[src] >= 'a' && buf[src] <= 'z')
            { dst++; continue; }
        if (dst && buf[dst-1] != '\n')
            { buf[dst++] = '\n'; }
    }
}
```

---

Note: the *Kernighan-style* has a nice property: the

```
  for (src=dst=0; buf[dst] = buf[src]; src++) {...}
```

*guarantees* that the '\0' will have been written to the destination after the loop finishes. So, there is no possibility to forget it.  (except when breaking out of the loop, which whe don't do here)

---

(of course the *real* Kernighan-style would use pointers, and one-letter variables ;-)